# neo4j delete and create nodes & links

Tags: graph, neo4j

I used a for loop to delete **all** the nodes and links of a particular Node Label in the neo4j database. 
There is a scenario where One user triggers a delete of the nodes & links and another user triggers a create of nodes & links (using the same Node Label). The deletion haven't complete and the creation starts, may I know is there anyway I can check whether is the deletion completed before I start on the creation?
I am using java to delete and create the nodes & links in neo4j database. 
Sorry for my bad description.

Comment: You can just check the number of node with the labels .... but I assume you have problem of race condition, otherwise you will not ask this question. So can you explain your problem behind this question ?

Comment: @logisima, I can actually check the total number of nodes for the label that is currently deleting but how long should I run the while loop and make sure it won't become an infinite loop? I am just wondering if there is any other solution? I am using version neo4j 2.1.